# Vector of Custom Objects

Tags: c++, object, inheritance, vector, sfml

I am trying to create a vector of custom objects defined in a header file and then initialize them in the actual cpp file. I'm getting the following errors in Visual Studio:

```
error C2976: 'std::vector' : too few template arguments
error C2065: 'Particle' : undeclared identifier
error C2059: syntax error : '>'
```

In the code below, the vector is defined in Explosion.h.

#### Particle.h:

```
#pragma once
class Particle : public sf::CircleShape {
public:
    float speed;
    bool alive;
    float vx;
    float vy;
    Particle(float x, float y, float vx, float vy, sf::Color color);
    ~Particle();
};
```

#### Particle.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Particle.h"

Particle::Particle(float x, float y, float vx, float vy, sf::Color color) {
    // Inherited
    this->setPosition(x, y);
    this->setRadius(5);
    this->setFillColor(color);

    // Player Defined Variables
    this->speed = (float).05;
    this->alive = true;
    this->vx = vx;
    this->vy = vy;
}

Particle::~Particle() {
}
```

#### Explosion.h:

```
static const int NUM_PARTICLES = 6;

#pragma once
class Explosion {
public:
    std::vector<Particle*> particles;
    bool alive;
    Explosion();
    ~Explosion();
};
```

#### Explosion.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Particle.h"
#include "Explosion.h"

Explosion::Explosion() {
    this->alive = true;

    // Add Particles to vector
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PARTICLES; i++) {
        this->particles.push_back(new Particle(0, 0, 0, 0, sf::Color::Red));
    }
}

Explosion::~Explosion() {
}
```

I'm sure there is something fundamentally wrong here since C++ is fairly new to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell `Explosion.h` what a `Particle` is.

In this case, `Explosion.h` is using `Particle*`, so a *forward declartion* will suffice.

**Explosion.h**

```
class Particle; // forward declaration of Particle

class Explosion {
// ...
};
```

You could also simply `#include "Particle.h`, however as your projects increase using forward declarations (instead of direct includes) can significantly reduce your build times.

Comment: Is the forward declaration necessary? It just looks like `Explosion.h` needs to `#include "Particle.h"`.

Comment: Either way would work.  Forward declarations will be preferred as the code base grows, as reducing the number of direct includes can significantly reduce build times.

Comment: Also suggest him to avoid C raw pointers, new and delete; in favor of leak-free smart pointers

Comment: @ssell: You might instead say, "Is `including` the file necessary? It looks like `Explosion.h` just needs to forward declare the class."

Comment: @Chad  - but the only place that includes `explosion.h` has `#include "particle.h"` immediately preceding it...?

Comment: @Manu343726 As I am new to this, what do you mean by "leak-free smart pointers"? Maybe a link to some documentation?

Comment: @Mitch (In addition to wikipedia's link): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one

Comment: @Manu343726 from what I've read, a smart pointer can not be used with a std::vector. What do you suggest?

Comment: @Mitch: I suggest you read something more accurate. C++11's standard smart pointers can be stored in containers quite happily. (That wasn't the case before 2011, but hopefully you're learning modern C++).